# Problema de navegabilidade utilizando Button em Bootstrap

Tags: css, jsf-2.2, bootstrap-3

Criei um projeto JSF e estou utilizando Bootstrap, e estou tentando implementar botões no meu projeto e não estou conseguindo colocar navegabilidade nelas, veja abaixo;

assim funcionar;

```
<li ><a href="/Terezinha.Bandeira" >Inicio</a></li>
```

assim não funciona;

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" outcome="/Terezinha.Bandeira/" >Inicio</button>
```

eu quero utilizar esse cara aqui em baixo, mas não consigo;

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large button</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize os componentes do jsf assim:

`<h:commandButton action="/Terezinha.bandeira" value="Inicio" styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" />`

Comment: valeu, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Tente desta maneira:

```
<a href="/Terezinha.Bandeira">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large button</button>
</a>
```